# Combine Rx Streams based on Id

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I have 2 streams emitting objects, one of type `A` and other of type `B`. They both contain, field which we will call `id`.

```
Observable<A> observableA = // by calling service A
Observable<B> observableB = // by calling service B
```

I want to combine these two streams into a single stream of object `C` which will contain data from both objects.

```
Observable<C> observableC = //Some fuction to merge observableA and observableB
```

The order in which the objects are emitted from observableA and observableB can be different. eg observableA can emit object with id 1 first, but observableB might emit object with id 2.

One approach I found to do this is keep put elements in 2 diffent Map's(MapA and MapB) as they are emitted and emit `C` when values are present in both Maps.

```
Map<String,A> mapA = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,B> mapB = new HashMap<>();

Observable<C> observableC = Observable.merge(observableA,observableB).map(obj->{
 if(obj instanceof A) {
  if(mapB.containsKey(((A)obj).getId()){
      //create object C
  } else {
      mapA.put(((A)obj).getId());
  }
 }
 if(obj instanceof B){
   // same checks as above
 })
```

I wanted to know if there is any cleaner way to do this( probably using some rx java operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`groupBy`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#groupBy-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) operator for this:

```java
    Observable.merge(s1, s2)
        .groupBy(obj -> obj.getId())
        .flatMapSingle(grp -> grp.toList()
            .map(l -> /* create object C here */)
        )
        .subscribe();
```

`groupBy` will break your source `Observable` instance into separate `GroupedObservable` instances, with one instance for each group, as determined by the value returned by the key selector function you pass to `groupBy`. In this case, you'd get one `GroupedObservable` for each unique ID returned by all the calls to `getId`. From there, we combine all the objects that share an ID into a list. At that point, you're free to use all those objects to create an instance of `C`.